# C compilation error - expression must have a constant value

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I got a code from an old project implementing AES on 802.15.4
It defines the the default key like this:

```
static uint8_t default_key_source[8] = {0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

and afterwards define a table which uses this in the following manner:

```
uint8_t mac_key_table[34] =
{
    // KeyIdLookupList[1].LookupData : macDefaultKeySource || g_Sec_KeyIndex_1
    default_key_source[0], // LookupData[0]
    default_key_source[1], // LookupData[1]
    default_key_source[2], // LookupData[2]
    default_key_source[3], // LookupData[3]
    default_key_source[4], // LookupData[4]
    default_key_source[5], // LookupData[5]
    default_key_source[6], // LookupData[6]
...
}
```

I get "expression must have a constant value" error on compilation. which is strange because it used to compile on different compiler (don't know exactly which, but I'm using IAR embedded workbench for ARM)

I tried adding const before the static declaration of the default_key_source. but it didn't help, I get that the compiler can't initialize a structure with variables, however these variables are constants, so what's the problem here ?

Comment: It is possible that the other compiler is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to deal with such a situation in C is to use a macro,  to be sure that you'd have to define the constants only in one place:

```
#define DEFAULT_KEY_SOURCE 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

// if you really need that variable
static default_key_source[8] = { DEFAULT_KEY_SOURCE };

uint8_t mac_key_table[34] =
{
  DEFAULT_KEY_SOURCE,
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

C requires you to have constant initializers if the variable has static storage duration. In your case the `mac_key_table` array is declared at file-scope and objects declared at file-scope have static storage duration.

In C the value of an object is not considered to be a constant. You tried to add the `const` keyword but in C `const` does not qualify an object to be *constant* but rather to be *read-only*.

Examples of constant expressions in C are literals, expressions with literals or enum members.